# How to send srt files over http

Tags: python-2.7, facebook-graph-api, srt

I am able to upload videos to Facebook via their Graph API, but unable to upload captions (cc) for those videos. According to their  [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/video-caption)  on uploading video captions only the video id, locale, and srt filename must be provided. However, when posting the request

```
r = requests.post("https://graph.facebook.com/v" + str(self.version) + "/" + path + "?" +
    post_data, files={captions_file: open(captions_file, 'rb')})
```

this is the result:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Invalid file. Expected file of one of the following types:
    application\/octet-stream","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

My confusion is the documentation specifies the caption file as filename.locale.srt, but the error specifies a file of MIME type application/octet-stream which a .srt file does not apply.

How can a .srt file be sent via application/octet-stream?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to upload captions for the facebook videos, but the only error I was getting was "(#100) Invalid file. Expected file of one of the following types: application/octet-stream".

So I wrote a ticket in facebook and seems like this is valid bug.

> I'm trying to add captions to video, but the only error I'm getting is 
>   "Invalid file. Expected file of one of the following types: application/octet-stream"
>
> The file that I'm using is http://www.apps.bg/filename.bg_BG.srt
>
> Steps to reproduce the bug:
>   1. Trying to upload captions from api ( /v2.4/video_id/captions )

And the answer that I got was

> "We have managed to reproduce this issue and it appears to be a valid
>   bug. We are assigning this to the appropriate team."

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1470577926590877

So we have to wait to fix it - or if someone finds a workaround.
Hope that this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution is to using file locally ad pass it instead of URL address. Something like this:

```
curl -i -X POST -F "captions_file=@\"subs.bg_BG.srt\"" https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/***/captions?access_token...
```